# How to find number the number of a specific character in a word?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char, string-length

I'm trying to make a program that whenever a character (for examine 'a') is found it prints it and the move on to next character to check. Keeps doing it until the end of the word.length.
It is what I have done so far but does not work,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    String word = in.next();
    String a = "a";
    int i;
    char found = 0;
    char F;

    for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        F = word.charAt(i);

        if (F == found)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: How does it not work? What output you get?

Comment: You are comparing to `found` instead of `a`...

Comment: for not debugging yourself

Comment: @RohitJain I dont get any output.

Comment: @Aquillo but I cant compare a to F because F is a char.

Comment: You should store `a` not as a `String` but as a `char`. You COULD also do `String.valueOf(F)` to compare it, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: @AlexJj. I would suggest you to go through a good Java tutorial, rather than shooting in the dark - The one from Oracle would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    String word = in.next();        
    char F;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        F = word.charAt(i);
        if (F == 'a') {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String word = in.next();
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("a");
        Matcher matcher=p.matcher(word);
        boolean b=false;
        while(b=matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.start()+"");
        }
```

**Edit:**

**Pattern.compile("a");**

```
Compiles the given regular expression into a pattern
```

**p.matcher(word);**

```
Creates a matcher that will match the given input against this pattern.
```

If you would like to search for source string like `aba` then for all occurrence of expression `a`, it will do like

```
source:aba
index:012
```

we can see two occurences of the expression a: one start from position 0 and second starting from 2. so the output is `0 2`

Comment: Thanks for you post. It didn't work, but it looks so complicated to me. I haven't learnt about patterns and matchers yet.

Comment: Don't you think that introducing regex for this issue, specially when OP is learning the basics of programming, is an OverKill??

Comment: @AlexJj it's ok. I edited answer to explain you. so you can achieve same feature with regex also.  As your problem with `if` condition so do change with `if(F=='a')` condition.

Answer (score 0):

use this one simple

```
 string.indexOf("a");
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but where should I replace it?